# Using socket.io on a node.js server, would it be better to constantly emit data or allow client to compute given a timestamp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Sorry if the title is unclear, but essentially what I'm trying to do is create a concurrent timer between multiple clients. What I'm trying to do is have one client (let's call this client the *starter*) begin the timer. This begins a timer that will be seen by all clients connected to the server.

From what I gather, I have two options to go about this;

Option A; When the starter begins the timer, the timestamp is sent to the server and saved there, and then emitted to all connected clients. Computation for the timer is done on the client-side. When a client opens a connection, the timer status and timestamp is sent to the client.

Option B; When the starter begins the timer, the time stamp is sent to the server, and the interval as well as computation is done server-side. Each tick of the timer is emitted to the clients from the server side.

I would like to know the benefits and weaknesses of taking either approach, and if these approaches would even work. From what I can infer, Option A would reduce the load on the server but puts more load on the client, and the opposite is true for Option B.

Apologies as this is my first stackoverflow post as well as my first node.js project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can checkout [rooms](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/) in socketio it may remove a lot of overhead.

Approach A seems better because It would because sending the timestamp would be more accurate than sending a tick from the server because let's say due to network latency the tick is delivered later and if the client has no idea about the timestamp there may be inconsistency

Also if you had thousands of WebSocket connections it would be better to put such logic in your client and let the server only handle connection related logic.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Was hoping that I could turn this project for school into a full-featured webapp, and will probably go with Approach A so I'm more scalable.

Answer (score 1):

Either of those approaches should work ok.

I would recommend checking out Croquet (disclosure: I work here), which allows you to keep clients in sync without even hitting your nodejs server. One of our demo applications actually does what you're describing out of the box!

https://croquet.studio/sdk/docs/tutorial-1_1_hello_world.html

Comment: I'm really interested in this! However, as my project is for school and my groupmates may have trouble understanding croquet as opposed to socket.io, I'll certainly keep Croquet bookmarked for when I build an application on my own. Appreciate the answer.